# Compiling js directories & node modules into single js file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

So I have a question, I'm looking into compiling all of my .js files along with the node modules also into one single .js file.

I currently have all of my `import` statements inside `main.js`, and then I have my babel script using the following: `"js-build": "babel js --out-file js/all.js --ignore js/main/main.js",` that takes all the imports from main.js and compiles it to `all.js`.

**Problem**:
It doesn't overwrite the files and I can't import node_modules, does someone have any recommendations on traditional ways to use npm to compile js files? Do you recommend things such as webpack? I'd like to stay away from gulp.

Comment: Is your question about transpiring Typescript? Javascript is not compiled. If you place all of your JavaScript source into a single file, you don't need `import` statements. Concatenating files together is easy from the command line of any operation system. You don't need webpack, gulp or any other command runner.

Answer (score 0):

i can do it by remove

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```